# Android: Fixed top menu

Tags: android, android-menu

How do I create a top bar menu for Android as I would for another phone?

I already created a menu for the bottom, but I couldn't find anything to create a fixed visible menu on top (a bar menu). Am I missing something? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "top bar menu" in Android, assuming you are referring to something like the bar at the top of an Windows window or the OS X screen. You are welcome to create something of your own, but there is no built-in platform support for such a concept.

Spend some time with existing Android applications, and you will find few (if any) that implement a "fixed visible menu on top". If you find one that does, post some screenshots of it in action and perhaps we can make some suggestions on how to implement it.

Comment: I will have to investigate further, but I think I was referring to a TabActivity. This is something I already saw in many applications, not something of an alien world. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it myself but I believe you could do it using the merge xml technique explained by Romain Guy here [link text](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html). Instead of putting the menu bar at the bottom, use the android:layout_alignParentTop="true" attribute on the menu items container. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will check it out later. Thank you John J Smith.